Python Script to grab .geojson files from my N drive in many different folders and place in one folder?
Is there a Python Script to grab .geojson files from my N drive in many different folders and place in one folder?
My ultimate goal is to then take this folder full of .geojson files and run a ArcGIS Pro batch data import tool.

Search in Windows explorer, drag and drop all in the folder of your choice

Also asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78280818/42659

You can use shutil and os:
import os
from shutil import copyfile
n_drive_path = r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/" #The folder to search for geojson files. Change it
out_folder = r"/home/bera/Desktop/test/" #The folder to copy them to. Change it

files_to_copy = [] #An empty list
for root, folder, files in os.walk(n_drive_path):
    for file in files: #For each file in all folders and subfolders in n_drive_path
        if file.endswith(".geojson"): #If it is a geojson
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file) #Create a full path to the file
            files_to_copy.append(fullname) #Append it to the list

#print(files_to_copy)
#['/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/points_on_lines.geojson', '/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/nearly_identical_points.geojson', '/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/Rectangle_lines.geojson', '/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/nearly_identical_points2.geojson']

for srcfile in files_to_copy: #For each file in the list
    #srcfile is for example: '/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/nearly_identical_points2.geojson'
    filename = os.path.basename(srcfile) #Extract only the filename from the full path
    dstfile = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
    #Dstfile is now: '/home/bera/Desktop/test/nearly_identical_points2.geojson'
    copyfile(src=srcfile, dst=dstfile)

shutil.copyfile, os.walk, os.path.join, os.path.basename

Many alternative ways to do this... this is a solution using Path.glob:
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

src_dir = Path("C:/temp/test_recursivecopy/src")
dst_dir = Path("C:/temp/test_recursivecopy/dst")

files = src_dir.glob("**/*.geojson")
for file in files:
    shutil.copy(file, dst_dir)

